# Android (Java): Getting GPS location accuracy

Tags: java, android, gps

How do I log the GPS accuracy in meters with getAccuracy() in Android?
The following is my code. When I run it, I get a build error. I added in the getAccuracy() method, but strangely it returns an error.

```
package com.example.yires.locationdemo;

import android.Manifest;
import android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.i("Location",location.toString());
                Log.i("GetAccuracy",location.getAccuracy());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
        } else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in Android, so would appreciate any code help or explanation. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To log float value, use `String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy());`

```
Log.i("HasAccuracy", String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy());
```

Comment: You're welcome! Mark it as accepted answer! @moonfairy

Comment: Tried to earlier but couldn't, now I can! Thanks!

Comment: its returning me 2000.0 what is the measurement mm or m ?

Comment: The value of the Accuracy is intended in meters